# MySQL - exactly match multiple IDs in the same column

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Consider the following data. This table, `t1`, maps substance identifiers (`substance_id`) to corresponding filters (`filter_id`). The `id` column is an auto-incrementing PK.

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| id      | substance_id | filter_id |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 7892022 |           26 |      2681 |
| 7892021 |          750 |      2680 |
| 7892020 |          750 |      2679 |
| 7892019 |          750 |      2677 |
| 7892018 |          750 |      2676 |
| 7892017 |          300 |      2680 |
| 7892016 |          300 |      2679 |
| 7892015 |           20 |      2681 |
| 7892014 |           20 |      2677 |
| 7892013 |            5 |      2681 |
| 7892012 |            5 |      2680 |
| 7892011 |            5 |      2679 |
| 7892010 |            5 |      2678 |
| 7892009 |            5 |      2677 |
| 7892008 |            5 |      2676 |
```

I'm trying to write a query which returns the `substance_id` when an **exact set** of `filter_id`'s are provided.

I can't use `IN()` to do this because that will match **any** of the `filter_id`s provided which isn't what I want to do. I've shown an example of this later.

In the sample data above the only `substance_id` which is on all 3 of these `filter_id`s

- 2676
- 2677
- 2678

is `substance_id` 5.

If I write this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE filter_id = 2676 AND filter_id = 2677 AND filter_id = 2678;
```

It returns 0 rows.

The following SQL returns 2 rows. However, this isn't what I'm looking for because `substance_id` 750 is not on all 3 of the `filter_id`s specified.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE filter_id = 2676 AND 2677 AND 2678;
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| id      | substance_id | filter_id |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 7892008 |            5 |      2676 |
| 7892018 |          750 |      2676 |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If I were to use `IN` I'll get 6 rows, which definitely isn't what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE filter_id IN(2676, 2677, 2678);
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| id      | substance_id | filter_id |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| 7892008 |            5 |      2676 |
| 7892018 |          750 |      2676 |
| 7892009 |            5 |      2677 |
| 7892014 |           20 |      2677 |
| 7892019 |          750 |      2677 |
| 7892010 |            5 |      2678 |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I understand that the `IN()` condition above isn't the right approach because it will match *any* of the `filter_id`s specified.

I don't understand how to write an `AND` condition which matches exactly the 3 `filter_id`s listed earlier and nothing else (e.g. partial matches where the substance is on 2 of the 3 filters should be excluded).

Is this possible in MySQL 8?

Comment: `AND 2677 AND 2678` aren't linked to `filter_id`. MySQL sees two non-zero integers evaluated as logical expressions so they're both TRUE and both conditions match for every row.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks. I realised that even after typing it out. I was trying to show approaches I had tried without success. I understand why that doesn't work.

Comment: You should drop the surrogate PK and use `(substance_id, filter_id)` instead, with a secondary index on `(filter_id, substance_id)` - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mN8dFZSo)

Answer (score 2):

A simple having count would do the trick

```
select substance_id 
from t1
where filter_id in (2676,2677,2678)
group by substance_id
having count(distinct filter_id) = 3;
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dtpk2iYM)